# ORACLE - sorting data by shifts

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've got a table with date_create - date type(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), and id_number.
I need to count number of id's created between two shifts - from 8 am to 8 pm and from 8 pm to 8 am count them and grup by exatc day of shift. How can i do it?

Comment: Can u provide some sample data?

Comment: id's are simply numeric, and dates in date type looks like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample data i have generated with the use of cte

```
with cte as
        (

        select 1 as id,sysdate+(1/24) as date1 from dual
        union all
        select 2 as id,sysdate+(2/24) date1 from dual
        union all
        select 4 as id,sysdate+(1/24) date1 from dual
        union all
        select 3 as id,sysdate+(3/24) date1 from dual
        union all
        select 5 as id,sysdate+(3/24) date1 from dual
        union all
        select 8 as id,sysdate+(9/24) date1 from dual
        union all
        select 6 as id,sysdate+(9/24) date1 from dual
        union all
        select 7 as id,sysdate+(17/24) date1 from dual
        )  

 select * from cte
```

**Results** after executing above we got some sample data

```
    ID          DATE1
    1   November, 30 2015 07:02:53
    2   November, 30 2015 08:02:53
    4   November, 30 2015 07:02:53
    3   November, 30 2015 09:02:53
    5   November, 30 2015 09:02:53
    8   November, 30 2015 15:02:53
    6   November, 30 2015 15:02:53
    7   November, 30 2015 23:02:53
```

After this i have executed below query along with above cte.

```
SELECT count(created_id) created_count
    ,CASE 
        WHEN date1 BETWEEN 8
                AND 20
            THEN '8 am to 8pm'
        ELSE '9 pm to 7 am'
        END type_1
FROM (
    SELECT id AS created_id
        ,to_number(to_char(date1, 'HH24')) date1
    FROM cte
    ) a
GROUP BY CASE 
        WHEN date1 BETWEEN 8
                AND 20
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN date1 BETWEEN 8
                AND 20
            THEN '8 am to 8pm'
        ELSE '9 pm to 7 am'
        END
```

**Results**

```
CREATED_COUNT    TYPE_1
5               8 AM TO 8PM
3               9 PM TO 7 AM
```

Note: Above example i have done with my sample data and the details provided by you in your post.

Comment: Bet you $50 we never see @user2603622 again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this query. It might help you.

```
SELECT COUNT(1),
  shift
FROM
  (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sht_time,'HH24:MI'),'HH24:MI') BETWEEN TO_DATE('08:00','HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('20:00','HH24:MI')
      THEN '8am_8pm'
      ELSE '8pm_8am'
    END shift,
    ID_NO
  FROM emp_sft
  )a
GROUP BY A.SHIFT;
```